# Preload association with non-default belongs_to atom

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm using Ecto 2.0 and trying to run this query:

```
query = from e in EmpireInstance,
        where: e.user_id == ^user.id,
        preload: [:board]
```

the schema for board looks like this:

```
schema "board_instances" do  
  belongs_to :empire, PlexServer.EmpireInstance
  has_many :board_pieces, BoardTileInstance

  timestamps
end
```

EmpireInstance schema:

```
schema "empire_instances" do
  ...

  belongs_to :user, PlexServer.User
  has_one :board, PlexServer.BoardInstance
  ...

  timestamps
end
```

I'm getting this error:

> ** (Ecto.QueryError) deps/ecto/lib/ecto/association.ex:392: field `PlexServer.BoardInstance.empire_instance_id` in `where` does not exist in the schema in query:
>
> ```
> from b in PlexServer.BoardInstance,
>    where: b.empire_instance_id in ^[1],
>    select: {b.empire_instance_id, b}
> ```

It looks like it's still trying to use the default belongs_to id of module_name + _id. Is there way to solve this, besides changing the belongs_to atom back to default?

Here's the code where the query is made:

```
def show(conn, _) do
  user = Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn)

  query = from e in EmpireInstance,
        where: e.user_id == ^user.id,
        preload: [:board]

  case Repo.one(query) do
    nil -> 
      conn
      |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
      |> json(%{errors: ["No associated empire"]})
    empire ->  
      render(conn, PlexServer.EmpireInstanceView, "show.json", empire: empire)
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please add the schema of `EmpireInstance`?

Comment: @Dogbert there ya go!

Comment: Are you sure that error message is for the query at the top of the question? (Just wanted to confirm.)

Comment: @Dogbert I added the code where I make the query. I'm 90% sure its coming from the query.

Comment: Thanks, looks good. I'm also confused why it's using `empire_instance_id` when `belongs_to`'s [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#belongs_to/3) implies it should use association name + `_id`, so `empire_id`. What happens if you add `, foreign_key: :empire_id` after `belongs_to :empire, PlexServer.EmpireInstance`?

Comment: @Dogbert no change unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [has_one/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_one/3) docs:

> :foreign_key - Sets the foreign key, this should map to a field on the other schema, defaults to the underscored name of the current schema suffixed by _id

Since the current_schema is `empire_instance`, the key is `empire_instance_id`

Perhaps you have your `belongs_to` and `has_one` the wrong way round? Or you created the keys in the database the wrong way round.

If not, could you post your migration files?

Comment: Ah I was missing :foreign_key on my has_xxx associations! Thank you